# What is the difference between >= and => in Java?

Tags: java, operators

In Stanford Programming Methodology Lecture 6, Professor Mehran Sahami said there is a difference between `>=` and `=>` in Java.

I know what `>=` is used for, but I have never seen `=>` (at least till I heard from the Professor) in Java. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Where have you seen `=>` in valid code? (In C# it's used for lambda expressions and expression-bodied members, but in Java `->` is used...)

Comment: @JonSkeet no, just that Professor Mehran said there is a difference. I looked up google but couldn't find anything, so I asked just in case

Comment: i also never heard `=>` symbol in java. this is spaceship operator `<=>`, which is used in groovy like this `assert (1 <=> 1) == 0`

Comment: so I guess what Professor meant was that >= and => is not equivalent to each other, what I thought he meant was >= and => are two different operators, which judging by the comments, is not the case. Thanks for the comments guys, really appreciate it

Comment: should I delete the post? dont really think its gonna be useful to future visitors

Comment: Have you tried => in real code?

Comment: Voting to close, this doesn't look like it would be useful for future readers, given the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

`>=` means "greater than or equal to".

`=>` means "the Java compiler is about to throw up".